# Method in the type is not applicable to arguments

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm a newbie working on a basic class creation tutorial and have been given the below instructions.

```
1) Create a new class called Book.
2) Create fields for title, author, numPages, and isbn.
3) Create a method called toString that appropriately describes the book.
4) In the file, BookRunner.java:
  a) Declare two book variables
  b) Instantiate two book objects and set their fields.
  c) Print descriptions of the book objects using their toString methods.
```

So I've been working with two classes as instructed, and you can see the code below

```
public class Book {
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public String numPages;
    public String isbn;

    public void toString(String bookName) {
        String description = "Title:" + title + "Author"+ author + "Num. of pages" + numPages + "ISBN" + isbn; 
        System.out.println(description);
    }

public class Ex1_BookRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book firstBook;
        Book secondBook;

        firstBook = new Book();
        secondBook = new Book();

        firstBook.title = "One Piece";
        firstBook.author = "Oda-Sensei";
        firstBook.numPages = "100";
        firstBook.isbn = "123456";

        secondBook.title = "Life of Megan Fox";
        secondBook.author = "Micheal Bay";
        secondBook.numPages = "200";
        secondBook.isbn = "098765";

        toString(firstBook);
        toString(secondBook);
    }
}
```

My code shows no errors until the last two lines where I call the method `toString`.

I get the error below

```
The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (Book)
```

Am I making some fundamental error somewhere in my method declaration? I've looked at other posts on SO with the same question but I have trouble understanding the explanations given because they mostly cover code syntax I haven't learnt yet.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Seems to me like `numPages` would be better suited as an `int`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try our toString method as

```
 public String toString() {
   String discription= "Title:" + title + "Author"+ author + "Num. of pages" + numPages + "ISBN" + isbn;
    return discription;
}
```

and your print statement in your main method should also look like this

```
   System.out.println(firstBook.toString());
   System.out.println(secondBook.toString());
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try `firstBook.toString();` - this produces a String, if you want to see it, you can do something like `System.out.println(firstBook.toString());`.  The error is telling you that there is no method toString that takes a book as a parameter.  What you want instead is to call the toString() method *on* the instance of Book that you have created.

Answer (score 0):

Change them to:

```
firstBook.toString();
secondBook.toString();
```

You can call the default .toString() method on the firstBook and secondBook that you've created. But since you didn't define a toString method that takes a Book object as a parameter, passing a Book object into toString() produces the aforementioned error.

In fact, your error line explains this quite clearly:

```
The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (Book)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two public classes in the same class

```
        public class Book {
//your codes or variables
}
    public class Ex1_BookRunner {
//your code or variables
}
```

Try this

Comment: This is incorrect. Also, this question already has an accepted answer.